# Python : ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code that send mails.
My directory is built like this:

```
├── __init__.py
├── lib
│   ├── a.py
│   ├── b.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

In `a.py` I'm trying to import `b.py` with the line: `from lib import b`, but it tells me that `lib` is not a module.
When I type `import b` it tells me that `b` is not a module.
Same in `main.py`
What can I do?

Comment: In `a.py` try `import .b` (noting the `.` before the `b`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in `main.py`, you want to use content from `a.py` that imports content from `b.py`, so:

- in `main.py` import `a`: `from lib import a`,
- in `a.py` import `b`: `from lib import b`.

Comment: Great to see, have a good day!